# Playing audio using Gtk's broadway

Tags: linux, gtk

I have several Gtk3 apps that I sometimes display in a browser using Broaday.

When running an app on the desktop (Linux in my case), it plays sound by running Sox's "play" command.  This obviously won't work for Broadway.

Is there any way to pass audio data to `broadwayd` (or tell it to play a file) so it the browser will play the sound?

My code is Perl, but I'm open to suggestions in any language.

Comment: No, Broadway would either have to be extended beyond the scope of a Gdk backend or you would use another protocol. Pulseaudio can play over the network for example.